# Can we two operator between 3 variables in C++

Tags: c++, if-statement, boolean, implicit-conversion, inequality

I want to compare four integers and see whether they are equal or not. So wrote the following,

```
    int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4;
    if (a != b != c != d)
    {
        //do something
    }
```

This apparently shows no error. But, in fact, giving the wrong answer.
Can someone explain this please?

Comment: You'll need to check `a != b`, `a != c`, `a != d`, `b != c`, `b != d`, `c != d`. If all conditions are true, none of the variables are equal... If I haven't made an error somewhere

Comment: `a != b != c != d` is equal to `((a != b) != c) != d`. That is you compare the integer values of `a` and `b`, and then the boolean result of that is compared to the integer value of `c`, and the boolean result of that is compares to the integer value `d`.

Comment: The `!=` operator acts on two operands.  But it is left-right associative, so `a != b != c != d` is equivalent to `((a != b) != c) != d`.    `a != b` gives a result of `true` which is promoted (for purposes of comparison with an `c`) to `int` with value `1`.   That is not equal to `c`, so `((a != b) != c)` gives a `true` which is again promoted to an `int` with value `1` - which is not equal to `d`.

Comment: You chose a pretty bad example - `1 != 2 != 3 != 4` actually does evaluate to `true` as one might believe, but not for the reason you were expecting. `4 != 3 != 2 != 1`, in the other hand...

Comment: What did you expect `a != b != c != d` to mean? `a != b && b != c && c != d`, or that all of the values are unique?

Comment: some examples would help: eg `1 1 1 2` all same -> `false`, all unique `false`, but `1 2 3 4` all same -> `false`, all unique -> `true`

Answer (score 6):

The condition in the if statement

```
if (a != b != c != d)
```

can be equivalently rewritten like

```
if ( ( ( a != b  ) != c ) != d )
```

The first subexpression `a != b` evaluates to boolean `true`. So you have

```
if ( ( true != c ) != d )
```

The subexpression `true != c` is implicitly converted to

```
if ( ( 1 != c ) != d )
```

which is clearly not what you want, although it is valid C++.

It seems you mean something like the following

```
if ( ( a != b ) && ( b != c ) && ( c != d ) )
```

Comment: Hope you don't mind my small edit. (And have an upvote.)

Comment: `if ( ( a != b ) && ( b != c ) && ( c != d ) )` allows `a == d`. `if (std::set{a, b, c, d}.size() == 4)` seems more appropriate.

Comment: @Bathsheba: unclear what OP wants. I understand all distinct numbers. Not, no consecutive duplicates numbers.

Comment: @Jarod42 To construct a set is too slow and unnecessary, please see my answer.

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin: `all_equal` doesn't need `set`, `all_different` (to each other) is another story. Equality is transitive, not unequality.

Comment: @Jarod42 I don't think we have to use set to check `all_different`, we can manually write the long boring statements, and I also think it can be solve with fold expression, but I haven't got the solution by far.

Answer (score 2):

`if (a != b != c != d)` can't be used to check if all values are equal. Besides the existed answers, we may also use the c++17 fold expression, its general and can avoid some redundant code(We can check any numbers/any types of variables).

```cpp
template <typename Args0, typename... Args>
bool all_equal(Args0 const& args0, Args const&... args) {
  return ((args0 == args) && ... && true);
}

TEST(check_equal, general) {
  ASSERT_TRUE(all_equal(1));
  ASSERT_FALSE(all_equal(1, 0));
  ASSERT_FALSE(all_equal(0, 1));
  ASSERT_FALSE(all_equal(1, 0, 1));
  ASSERT_FALSE(all_equal(1, 0, 1, 1, 1));
  ASSERT_TRUE(all_equal(1, 1));
  ASSERT_TRUE(all_equal(1, 1, 1));
  ASSERT_TRUE(all_equal(1, 1, 1, 1));
}
```

Comment: `all_equal` is not the same as `all_different`. `all_different` would requires cartesian product with folding expression (as somethink like `(Count<Args, All>() + ... + 0) == sizeof...(Args)`).

Comment: @Jarod42 I agree with you, I will have a try. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use this function to check if all arguments are unequal:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>

template<typename T>
bool allunequal(std::initializer_list<T> L)
{
    std::vector<T> v(L);
    std::set<T> s;
    for (T& val : v) {
        if (s.find(val) != s.end()) {
            return false;
        }
        s.insert(val);
    }
    return true;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << allunequal({1,2,3,4}) << std::endl;
}
```

Use it like `if (allunequal({1,2,3,4})) {...}`.

Comment: Why? We want to know if all values are unequal to each other, right?

Comment: You might use `return std::set{L}.size() == L.size();` BTW.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number: *"using a std::set is rather wasteful,"* It is the `std::vector` which is :) (and for your interpretation, any extra container would be).

Comment: indeed, the vector is not needed. I was just careless. In fact you clearly state what problem the code solves and using a `set` is an elegant way to do that. I'll remove the comments, its up to OP to clarify in case they wanted "all same or not"

Comment: What should I use instead of the vector @Jarod42? A variadic function?

Comment: it is all right there in Jarods comment. You can replace the body of your `allunequal` with that single line. The vector is not needed, because the initializer list is already something you can iterate

Comment: From your code, you might already just do `for (T& val : L)`. and as shown in my first comment, you might construct the set direclty.

Comment: Thank you @Jarod42. That is a really elegant solution!

Answer (score -1):

Simple answer is to generate some permutations and just write it out by hand, verify it once or twice, put a comment for future sceptics and done:

```cpp
// DO NOT TOUCH, i checked it, it does what it should, and you'll break it
if (a != b && a != c && a != d && 
    b != c && b != d && c != d) {
    std::cout << "no duplicates!" << std::endl;    
} else {
    std::cout << "duplicates!" << std::endl;
}
```

Here's a more sophisticated solution which might be easier to understand and maintain, depending on your skill level (these also have better big-O complexity, but allocate and might throw, so be aware of those differences):

```cpp
if (std::set{a, b, c, d}.size() != 4) {
    std::cout << "duplicates!" << std::endl;
} else {
    std::cout << "no duplicates!" << std::endl;
}
```

or with `<algoritm>`:

```cpp
std::sort(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec));
if (std::adjacent_find(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec)) != std::end(vec)) {
    std::cout << "duplicates!" << std::endl;
} else {
    std::cout << "no duplicates!" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: The *"over-engineered"* solutions are `O(n log(n))` and not `O(n²)` as the hand written solution.

Comment: imho this is a prime example of a dangerous comment. Suppose someone does change the code but not the comment and what confusion that will cause for the next reader. Avoiding such comments in favour of clear and simple code is not "over engineering"

Comment: @Jarod42 O complexity is irrelevant here, as it's 4 elements, a fixed number of elements. And while the std::set method, for example, might have a better O complexity, you're completely forgetting that there's an implied *constant* time that is added to that. While my solution is O(n²)+C, with a miniscule C, the overengineered solution(s) do multiple indirections through function calls, allocate, and might even throw, so their real complexity is O(n log(n))+C with a C that is so incredibly huge that it's an absolute joke to even compare it to the "simple solution".

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number the std::set solution will also only consider a, b, c and d - if you add more variables to the code, you also have to go add it there. The inherent "manual work" required there doesn't change much. The danger of forgetting to add another variable to the set is just as large as the one for forgetting to add some permutations.

Comment: funny thing is: Complexity does matter. If you add another variable with your solution you have to add `O(n)` more conditions, even with `n=4` that is considerably more than 1.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I agree with that, and I agree that the comment is pretty bad, but in my mind it's a good idea to teach simple solutions first, and then show what you could do, too. It makes me very worried for our ecosystem if we teach beginners that, to compare 4 things for inequality, you should create two massive classes and use operator overloading. There's a consideration to "what is reasonable to teach" here, too.

Comment: I think you now refer to one answer specifically. If you read the comments below that answer you see that I suggested the author that they make it more clear that the answer is just a curiosity, not meant to be actually used and that the author seems to agree. In your answer on the other hand you write "Since most answers are totally over-engineered;" and I cannot agree to that when you want to imply that an error prone several line condition is better or simpler  than a function call